# Decimal in List not holding value or adding when supposed to. Keeps returning 0

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm creating a budget app. I have an entry box in which the user will input they value of an object/service called `OutgoingMonthlyCost` I also have a save button which saves the users input in to a list telling them the item name & the cost the routine is below.

```
void AddToBudget_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Budget Budget = new Budget()
        {
            OutgoingProductName = OProductName.Text,
            OutgoingMonthlyCost = Convert.ToDecimal(OMonthlyCost.Text)

        };

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<Budget>();
            int rowsAdded = conn.Insert(Budget);

        }

        DisplayAlert("Added!", "Your Monthly Item has been Added to Budget!", "OK");

        BindingContext = new Budget();

        OnAppearing();
    }
```

Once the item saves to the list I want to add up all `OutgoingMonthlyCost` Then subtract it from the input a user types in, which is `MonthlySalary` - This is an entry box in which the user will input how much they get monthly after tax. I have added all my code for the class below. I feel the routine `TotalBudget()` Is where the issue lies.

```
 private string outgoingProductName { get; set; }
    public string OutgoingProductName
    {
        get => outgoingProductName;
        set
        {
            outgoingProductName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OutgoingProductName");
        }
    }


    private decimal outgoingMonthlyCost { get; set; }
    public decimal OutgoingMonthlyCost
    {
        get => outgoingMonthlyCost;
        set
        {

            outgoingMonthlyCost = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OutgoingMonthlyCost");

        }

    }


    private decimal monthlySalary { get; set; }
    public decimal MonthlySalary
    {
        get => monthlySalary;
        set
        {

            monthlySalary = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MonthlySalary");
            TotalBudget();

        }

    }


    private string finalBudget { get; set; }
    public string FinalBudget
    {
        get => finalBudget;
        set
        {

            finalBudget = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FinalBudget");

        }

    }


    public void TotalBudget()
    {

        var Conversion = default(decimal);

        Conversion += OutgoingMonthlyCost;

        if (Conversion != 0)
        {

            FinalBudget = "£" + (MonthlySalary - Conversion);
        }

        else
        {
            FinalBudget = "£" + MonthlySalary;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

when converting a number to a string, C# gives you control over the formatting

```
FinalBudget = (MonthlySalary - Conversion).ToString("C");
```

"C" is a built in converter for currency, or you can use a [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: I have added that in mate thanks! I still cant get this to work Conversion doesnt seem to be working when I put += when debugging it is going through individually ie it will read through first time as 20 then if theres a second at 50 it will be 50 but it seems to run through it all at the end giving it a 0. It never actually adds either

Comment: `Conversion` is declared within the getter, so it will get reset to 0 every time it is called.  If you want it to maintain it's value, declare it as a class variable.